# N' INSERT INTO vs INSERT INTO

Tags: sql-server, unicode, character, insert-into

I'm using a custom library of .Net to access the sql server.

This library is executing this query in the server:

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO Testable (testcolumn1, testcolumn2) 
   VALUES (@const795, @const796) ', N'@const795 int, @const796 nvarchar(50)', 
   @const795=1803496, @const796='ÄÅÉæÆôöòÇ Münchenß дие Таль'
```

Result:

```
Column 1 : 1803496
Column 2 : ÄÅÉæÆôöòÇ Münchenß ??? ????
```

If I execute this query manually:

```
INSERT INTO Testable (testcolumn1, testcolumn2) 
VALUES (1803496,N'ÄÅÉæÆôöòÇ Münchenß дие Таль')
```

Result:

```
Column 1 : 1803496
Column 2 : ÄÅÉæÆôöòÇ Münchenß дие Таль
```

The  `N'INSERT INTO` don't should be store the parameters in UniCode codification? Why the second query is saving "дие Таль" good and the first query not?

The column 2 is nvarchar type and the collation of the column is Latin1_General_CI_AS.

On the other hand I have another problem because the library really is sending:

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO Testable (testcolumn1, testcolumn2)
  VALUES (@const795, @const796) ',N'@const795 int,@const796 nvarchar(50)',
  @const795=1803496, @const796= 'ÄÅÉæÆôöòÇ Münchenß ??? ????'
```

With question marks instead of russian characters. I know that because I have used SQL profiler to "sniff" the query coming from the library.

Debugging the query from the library I can see the correct value of this "дие Таль" characters until send the query to the database. But the sql profiler get "??? ????" characters· Why is happening that?

Answer (score 0):

The library needs to specify the "N" when you set @const796 to a value.  `@const796=N'ÄÅÉæÆôöòÇ Münchenß дие Таль'`

```
 exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO Testable (testcolumn1, testcolumn2) 
    VALUES (@const795, @const796) ', N'@const795 int, @const796 nvarchar(50)', 
    @const795=1803496, @const796=N'ÄÅÉæÆôöòÇ Münchenß дие Таль'
```